# Local pyspark can't access s3 files via AWS credential profile or environment variables?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I'm new to pyspark, have installed pyspark and related packages as shown below locally for setting up local dev/test environment for ETL big data stored on AWS S3 buckets.

```
spark 2.4.5
Scala version 2.11.12
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_231
hadoop-*.jars 2.7.3 (default hadoop jars that come with spark 2.4.5 package)

2 dependent jars downloaded to $SPARK_HOME/jars/: aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar, hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar
```

For accessing AWS from local SDK: ~/.aws/credentials file which stores multiple profiles, the [default] profile stores: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, and aws_session_token as a fedarated user.

Ideally would like to use spark conf : DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain to retrieve credentials from profile, but it seems doesn't work(: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain). Then manually extract credentials from that file and feed them to spark conf: TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider (as shown in the code below) or as environment variables in spark-env.sh conf files, but got Status Code: 403 Forbidden.

Here is some detail of the code and errors:

The following script tries to read a csv from AWS s3 bucket via the s3a scheme:

```
config = pyspark.SparkConf().setAll([
    ('fs.s3a.impl', 'org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem')
    ,("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider","com.amazonaws.auth.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider")
    ,("fs.s3a.access.key", "xxxx")
    ,("fs.s3a.secret.key", "xxxx")
    ,("fs.s3a.session.token", "xxxx")
])
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=config)
sc.setSystemProperty("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")
sql = SQLContext(sc)
df = (sql.read
         .format("csv")
         .option("header", "true")
         .load("s3a://bucket/prefix/file_name"))
```

It gives errors as follow, but the key, secret and token are valid as checked by boto3:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o130.load.
: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: xxxx, AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: Forbidden, S3 Extended Request ID: xxxx
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:798)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:421)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:232)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3528)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:976)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:956)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:892)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1426)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:557)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:545)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:545)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:359)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```

I've also tried the following settings:

1. ("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider",
   "com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChainAWSCredentialsProvider")
   it gives errors:
   com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
   at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:117)
2. set environment variables in spark-env.sh: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SESSION_TOKEN, which are valid for accessing s3 as tested by boto3, it gives same errors as using TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider:
   py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o130.load.
   : com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: xxxx, AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: Forbidden, S3 Extended Request ID: xxxx
3. tried other versions of aws-java-jdk.jar and hadoop-aws.jar
   native ones from latest hadoop installation 3.2.1:
   aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.375.jar, hadoop-aws-3.2.1.jar, hadoop-common-3.2.1.jar
   or the jars from hadoop 2.8.5 version
   it gives "NoSuchMethod" errors:
   py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o86.load.
   : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/StreamCapabilities

Really struggling here and would you please suggest what might be wrong here and what is the possible solution?
Much appreciated in advance

Comment: What are the working dependent jars? Although aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar, hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar are most recommended, but a closer look at the jar files, it is found that: 1) aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar : its DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain has only EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider, SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider, and InstanceCredentialsProvider, no profileCredentialsProvider or TemporaryCredentialsProvider classes. and 2) hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar has Basic,InstanceProfile(for EC2) and Anonymous AWSCredentialsProvider classes, how could they fetch credentials from profile or Temporary settings

Comment: what about trying it on Databricks community free Spark web interface, that works with S3 out of the box?